# bower with cryptojslib automatically adds many <script> tags

Tags: angularjs, bower, cryptojs

I've used Yeoman to scaffold my app (bower as dependency management) and `cryptojslib` is one of the packages I'm using. It ships with many algorithms, I actually only need `rollups/sha256.js`.

`bower` seems to automatically add `<script>` tags to the `index.html` to load all packages, but with `cryptojslib` it adds around 100 components and rollups and I only need to load one of them.
If I remove this from the `index.html` file, it comes back on the nexty `bower install` run.

Can I exclude a package from this html manipulation?

Answer (score 0):

Remember

**->** *You can't ignore on behalf of other packages/files if it has the dependency.*

The following way you can `ignore` some files not to add in your project while doing `bower install`

In your `bower.json` file add the following -

`{
  "ignore": "file_name_of_not_to_add" 
 }`

Comment: Thanks Altius. I don't want to ignore a dependency of `cryptojslib`. The package comes with a lot of rollups modules (that pack together everything needed for a specific algorithm) and I want to use only one of them (sha256). Apparently bower automatically adds <script> tags for all rollups in the package and that's a waste for me..